# regex: given a multiline string, how to match the text included after a specified string positioned at the beginning of each line?

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, match, cpu-word

Given this multiline text:

```
abc aaa
bbb abc ccc
abc ddd eee
fff abc
```

I want to match the `abc` word **at the beginning of each line** as first matching group, and the rest of the text **before the next** `abc` positioned at the beginning of the line.

So, this is the expected result match:

```
Match 1
Full match  `abc aaa
bbb abc ccc`

Group 1.    `abc`
Group 2.    ` aaa
            bbb abc ccc`

Match 2
Full match  `abc ddd eee
fff abc`

Group 1.    `abc`
Group 2.    ` ddd eee
            fff abc`
```

I have tried this regex (with multiline option):

```
/^(abc)([\w\s]+)/gm
```

But the result is wrong because it takes the text in total:

```
Match 1
Full match  `abc aaa
bbb abc ccc
abc ddd eee
fff abc`

Group 1.    `abc`
Group 2.    ` aaa
bbb abc ccc
abc ddd eee
fff abc`
```

How can I correct my regex to obtain the expected result?

Notice that the word "abc" can compare also on the rest of the "internal segment" of the string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
/^(abc\b)(.*(?:\r?\n(?!abc\b).*)*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBqGBB/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(abc\b)` - a whole word `abc` (remove `\b` if you do not need a whole word)
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!abc\b).*)*)` - Group 2 capturing

  - `.*` - the rest of the line that starts with `abc`
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!abc\b).*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `\r?\n(?!abc\b)` - a line break not followed with `abc`
    - `.*`  - the rest of the current line.